# Cython 0.21 installation/compilation error

Tags: python-2.7, pip, cython, easy-install, linux-mint

I have been attempting to install Cython 0.21 on Linux Mint 17. I have tried using pip:

```
sudo pip install Cython
```

and also downloading/unpacking Cython 0.21 and using python to compile/install using both:

```
python setup.py install
```

and

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

In each case, setup appears to go through the correct compilation sequence, however once it gets to what seems to be getting the current working directory (using `os.getcwdu()`) it results in

```
OSError: [Errno 34] Numerical result out of range (Full dump at end).
```

My current attempts to resolve have been:

- pip uninstall of Cython 0.20 Reinstallation of setuptools (previously
  I was receiving an `Attribute Error: no model object named
  'Distutils'`, when trying `sudo pip install --upgrade cython` from
  v0.20)
- pip installation of Cython 0.21
- easy_install installation ofCython 0.21
- Download and manual compilation/install of Cython 0.21 from [cython.org](http://cython.org).

I'm out of ideas, and can't find what seems to be an overflow error that occurs during the very compilation of Cython. My thinking is that there's something odd about the temp file structure it's creating...in `**setup_args`. It looks like this temp structure is iteratively being added to one really long path (I don't know what all the Cython/temp files are for), which maybe then just gives up and says I quit when calling `os.getcwdu()`?

**UPDATE: I have attempted to build w/ `--no-cython-compile` , which works, but the pure Python implementation isn't helpful here.**

**UPDATE2: I found the culprit. It appears that a package called `setuptools-cython` was sitting in the python system. Upon removal, all compiled fine. Something to watch for.**

Bug report maybe?

Python version:

```
Python 2.7.6-8 (for Ubuntu Trusty/14.04)
```

Kernel version:

```
Linux 3.13.0-24-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 23:30:00 UTC 2014 
x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

GCC version:

```
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2
```

Python setuptools version:

```
6.0.7
```

Installation dump w/ error using pip (same for each install):

```
==> sudo pip install cython
    Downloading/unpacking cython
    Downloading Cython-0.21.tar.gz (1.5MB): 1.5MB downloaded

Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/cython/setup.py) egg_info for package cython
        Compiling module Cython.Plex.Scanners ...
        Compiling module Cython.Plex.Actions ...
        Compiling module Cython.Compiler.Lexicon ...
        Compiling module Cython.Compiler.Scanning ...
        Compiling module Cython.Compiler.Parsing ...
        Compiling module Cython.Compiler.Visitor ...
        Compiling module Cython.Compiler.FlowControl ...
        Compiling module Cython.Compiler.Code ...
        Compiling module Cython.Runtime.refnanny ...
        Compiling module Cython.Tempita._tempita ...
```

<<(snipped, repetitious, goto first note of error)>>

```
        ERROR: [Errno 34] Numerical result out of range

        Extension module compilation failed, looks like Cython cannot run
        properly on this system.  To work around this, pass the option
        "--no-cython-compile".  This will install a pure Python version of
        Cython without compiling its own sources.
```

<<(The traceback)>>

```
        Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
File "/tmp/pip_build_root/cython/setup.py", line 337, in <module>
            **setup_args
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 111, in setup
            _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 266, in __init__
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 287, in __init__
            self.finalize_options()
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 300, in finalize_options
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2183, in require
            items = working_set.resolve(reqs, env, installer)
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 614, in resolve
            dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 857, in best_match
            return self.obtain(req, installer)
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 869, in obtain
            return installer(requirement)
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 338, in fetch_build_egg
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 613, in easy_install

          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 643, in install_item

          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 833, in install_eggs

          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1055, in build_and_install

          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1040, in run_setup

          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 68, in run_setup
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 114, in run
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 67, in runner
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 43, in _execfile
          File "/tmp/easy_install-oM3TIi/Cython-0.21/setup.py", line 337, in <module>
            **setup_args
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 111, in setup
            _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 266, in __init__
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 287, in __init__
            self.finalize_options()
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 300, in finalize_options
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2183, in require
            items = working_set.resolve(reqs, env, installer)
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 614, in resolve
            dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 857, in best_match
            return self.obtain(req, installer)
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 869, in obtain
            return installer(requirement)
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 338, in fetch_build_egg
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 613, in easy_install

          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 643, in install_item

          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 833, in install_eggs

          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1055, in build_and_install

          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1040, in run_setup

          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 68, in run_setup
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 114, in run
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 67, in runner
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 43, in _execfile
          File "/tmp/easy_install-oM3TIi/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-UA0lQE/Cython-0.21/setup.py", line 337, in <module>
            **setup_args
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 111, in setup
            _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 266, in __init__
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 287, in __init__
            self.finalize_options()
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 300, in finalize_options
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2183, in require
            items = working_set.resolve(reqs, env, installer)
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 614, in resolve
            dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 857, in best_match
            return self.obtain(req, installer)
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 869, in obtain
            return installer(requirement)
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 338, in fetch_build_egg
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 613, in easy_install

          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 643, in install_item

          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 833, in install_eggs

          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1055, in build_and_install

          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1040, in run_setup

          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 68, in run_setup
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 114, in run
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 67, in runner
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 43, in _execfile
```

<<(snipped - repetitious)>>

```
          File "/tmp/easy_install-oM3TIi/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-UA0lQE/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-8qfQMc/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-Qc_qzI/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-eb8bK_/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-BR3a7l/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-tA_dfC/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-SFBomd/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-4T8n8i/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-Gf2wwr/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-w4dZCL/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-03hPx9/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-SUfUfS/Cython-0.21/setup.py", line 337, in <module>
            **setup_args
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 111, in setup
            _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 266, in __init__
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 287, in __init__
            self.finalize_options()
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 300, in finalize_options
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2183, in require
            items = working_set.resolve(reqs, env, installer)
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 614, in resolve
            dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 857, in best_match
            return self.obtain(req, installer)
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 869, in obtain
            return installer(requirement)
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 338, in fetch_build_egg
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 613, in easy_install

          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 643, in install_item

          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 833, in install_eggs

          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1055, in build_and_install

          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1040, in run_setup

          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 68, in run_setup
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 114, in run
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 67, in runner
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 43, in _execfile
          File "/tmp/easy_install-oM3TIi/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-UA0lQE/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-8qfQMc/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-Qc_qzI/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-eb8bK_/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-BR3a7l/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-tA_dfC/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-SFBomd/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-4T8n8i/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-Gf2wwr/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-w4dZCL/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-03hPx9/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-SUfUfS/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-e", line 337, in <module>
            **setup_args
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 111, in setup
            _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 266, in __init__
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 287, in __init__
            self.finalize_options()
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 300, in finalize_options
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2183, in require
            items = working_set.resolve(reqs, env, installer)
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 614, in resolve
            dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 857, in best_match
            return self.obtain(req, installer)
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 869, in obtain
            return installer(requirement)
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 338, in fetch_build_egg
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 613, in easy_install

          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 643, in install_item

          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 833, in install_eggs

          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1055, in build_and_install

          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1040, in run_setup

          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 68, in run_setup
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 114, in run
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 67, in runner
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 43, in _execfile
          File "/tmp/easy_install-oM3TIi/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-UA0lQE/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-8qfQMc/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-Qc_qzI/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-eb8bK_/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-BR3a7l/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-tA_dfC/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-SFBomd/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-4T8n8i/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-Gf2wwr/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-w4dZCL/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-03hPx9/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-SUfUfS/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-e", line 337, in <module>
            **setup_args
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 111, in setup
            _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 266, in __init__
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 287, in __init__
            self.finalize_options()
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 300, in finalize_options
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2183, in require
            items = working_set.resolve(reqs, env, installer)
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 614, in resolve
            dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 857, in best_match
            return self.obtain(req, installer)
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 869, in obtain
            return installer(requirement)
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 338, in fetch_build_egg
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 613, in easy_install

          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 643, in install_item

          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 833, in install_eggs

          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1055, in build_and_install

          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1040, in run_setup

          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 68, in run_setup
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 114, in run
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 67, in runner
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 43, in _execfile
          File "/tmp/easy_install-oM3TIi/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-UA0lQE/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-8qfQMc/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-Qc_qzI/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-eb8bK_/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-BR3a7l/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-tA_dfC/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-SFBomd/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-4T8n8i/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-Gf2wwr/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-w4dZCL/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-03hPx9/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-SUfUfS/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-e", line 337, in <module>
            **setup_args
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 111, in setup
            _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 266, in __init__
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 287, in __init__
            self.finalize_options()
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 300, in finalize_options
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2183, in require
            items = working_set.resolve(reqs, env, installer)
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 614, in resolve
            dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 857, in best_match
            return self.obtain(req, installer)
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 869, in obtain
            return installer(requirement)
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 338, in fetch_build_egg
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 613, in easy_install

          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 643, in install_item

          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 833, in install_eggs

          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1055, in build_and_install

          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1040, in run_setup

          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 68, in run_setup
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 114, in run
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 67, in runner
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 43, in _execfile
          File "/tmp/easy_install-oM3TIi/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-UA0lQE/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-8qfQMc/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-Qc_qzI/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-eb8bK_/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-BR3a7l/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-tA_dfC/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-SFBomd/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-4T8n8i/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-Gf2wwr/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-w4dZCL/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-03hPx9/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-SUfUfS/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-e", line 337, in <module>
            **setup_args
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 111, in setup
            _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 266, in __init__
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 287, in __init__
            self.finalize_options()
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 300, in finalize_options
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2183, in require
            items = working_set.resolve(reqs, env, installer)
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 614, in resolve
            dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 857, in best_match
            return self.obtain(req, installer)
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 869, in obtain
            return installer(requirement)
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 338, in fetch_build_egg
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 613, in easy_install

          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 643, in install_item

          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 833, in install_eggs

          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1055, in build_and_install

          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1040, in run_setup

          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 68, in run_setup
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 114, in run
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 67, in runner
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 43, in _execfile
```

<<(This Madness continues for awhile...snip to end game)>>

```
          File "/tmp/easy_install-oM3TIi/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-UA0lQE/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-8qfQMc/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-Qc_qzI/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-eb8bK_/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-BR3a7l/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-tA_dfC/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-SFBomd/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-4T8n8i/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-Gf2wwr/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-w4dZCL/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-03hPx9/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-SUfUfS/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-e", line 266, in <module>
            compile_cython_modules(cython_profile, cython_compile_more, cython_with_refnanny)
          File "/tmp/easy_install-oM3TIi/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-UA0lQE/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-8qfQMc/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-Qc_qzI/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-eb8bK_/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-BR3a7l/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-tA_dfC/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-SFBomd/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-4T8n8i/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-Gf2wwr/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-w4dZCL/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-03hPx9/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-SUfUfS/Cython-0.21/temp/easy_install-e", line 210, in compile_cython_modules
            result = compile(pyx_source_file)
          File "Cython/Compiler/Main.py", line 622, in compile
            return compile_single(source, options, full_module_name)
          File "Cython/Compiler/Main.py", line 575, in compile_single
            return run_pipeline(source, options, full_module_name)
          File "Cython/Compiler/Main.py", line 439, in run_pipeline
            err, enddata = Pipeline.run_pipeline(pipeline, source)
          File "Cython/Compiler/Pipeline.py", line 328, in run_pipeline
            data = phase(data)
          File "Cython/Compiler/Pipeline.py", line 54, in generate_pyx_code_stage
            module_node.process_implementation(options, result)
          File "Cython/Compiler/ModuleNode.py", line 111, in process_implementation
            self.generate_c_code(env, options, result)
          File "Cython/Compiler/ModuleNode.py", line 328, in generate_c_code
            self.body.generate_function_definitions(env, code)
          File "Cython/Compiler/Nodes.py", line 398, in generate_function_definitions
            stat.generate_function_definitions(env, code)
          File "Cython/Compiler/Nodes.py", line 398, in generate_function_definitions
            stat.generate_function_definitions(env, code)
          File "Cython/Compiler/Nodes.py", line 4492, in generate_function_definitions
            self.body.generate_function_definitions(self.scope, code)
          File "Cython/Compiler/Nodes.py", line 398, in generate_function_definitions
            stat.generate_function_definitions(env, code)
          File "Cython/Compiler/Nodes.py", line 4525, in generate_function_definitions
            self.body.generate_function_definitions(env, code)
          File "Cython/Compiler/Nodes.py", line 398, in generate_function_definitions
            stat.generate_function_definitions(env, code)
          File "Cython/Compiler/Nodes.py", line 2975, in generate_function_definitions
            self.py_wrapper.generate_function_definitions(env, code)
          File "Cython/Compiler/Nodes.py", line 3115, in generate_function_definitions
            code.mark_pos(self.pos)
          File "Cython/Compiler/Code.py", line 1665, in mark_pos
            source_desc.get_escaped_description(), line, u'\n'.join(lines))
          File "Cython/Compiler/Scanning.py", line 145, in get_escaped_description
            self.get_description().encode('ASCII', 'replace').decode("ASCII")
          File "Cython/Compiler/Scanning.py", line 214, in get_description
            return os.path.relpath(self.path_description)
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 438, in relpath
            path_list = [x for x in abspath(path).split(sep) if x]
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 369, in abspath
            cwd = os.getcwdu()
        OSError: [Errno 34] Numerical result out of range
```

Comment: The first major/important thing whenever you're installing dependencies via a tool like pip is to ALWAYS do so in a virtual environment of sorts. The closest I could get for this says: "This slapd error generally indicates that the client sent a message that exceeded an administrative limit." Link = http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/network_administration_guides/ldap_administration/appendix-common-errors_Other_Errors.html

Comment: @Joe: True. And I do this for various packages, usually ones that are rather bulky and have a number of known dependencies, or for packages which appear to be underdeveloped, but potentially useful. I don't always do this with generally stable packages. The analogue you give makes me think there's still something strange with setup.py for Cython and/or setuptools, given the VERY long path, which in the past was known to give getcwdu() some headaches. I need to get more info on this and may present as a potential bug report if no other responses.

Comment: The previous python bug I refer to: http://bugs.python.org/issue2722.

Comment: I found that same link you did, but I didn't provide it as it referenced Python 2.4/5 and I assumed that the problem may have been fixed by now.

Comment: The manual installation of Cython with the `--no-cython-compile` option gives the same error?

Comment: I haven't done this as I don't want the 'pure' python setup (i.e. no C files). I tried upgrading protobuf, which imports stuff from Cython. The compilation sequence looks 'slightly' different, but the outcome is the same (errno 34). I don't see a benefit compiling Cython this way - that's not how it was intended. Additionally, many other packages rely on Cython in some way and don't ask for a pure python install. I can check this as a matter of bug hunting at least. Will edit w/ any findings.

Comment: Tried building with `--no-cython-compile`, which works, but things that depend on it end up with `AttributeError: 'module' object has not attribute 'Distutils'`. This was the error I received when I tried to upgrade v 0.20 and anything depending on Cython. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that a sneaky little package called `setuptools-cython` was sitting in the python system. Upon removal, all built fine. Something to watch for.

`pip uninstall setuptools-cython` was my solution to this.